# как вывести значение glm::vec2 и glm::mat2

Tags: c++, opengl, вектор

попробовал вывести (что там лежит):

```
glm::vec2 a(1.0f);       // 1.0f, 1.0f
printf("a = %d \n", a);
glm::vec2 b = a +1.0f;   // 2.0f, 2.0f
printf("b = %d \n", b);
float len = glm::length(a);
printf("len (a) = %f, \n", len);
float len1 = glm::length(b);
printf("len (b) = %f, \n", len1);
float dist = glm::distance(a,b);
printf("dist = %f, \n", dist);
```

Вот что выводит :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вывести вектор ???

```
           glm::mat2 m(0,1,2,3); // даже не понял как вывести
```

Как вывести матрицу ???

Comment: Я glm давно не использовал, но что, `std::cout << a;` не работает?

Comment: А у них полей x/y нет случайно? Типа `a.x`, `a.y` для vec2??? Или там оператор `[]`?? Типа `a[0]`, `a[1]`. [Вроде есть](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00020.html) А для матриц только оператор `[][]` : [описание mat2x2 в документации](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.2/api/a00010.html)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Подскажите пожалуйста, я многое не понимаю в опенгл, можете посмотреть мою сборку проекта вот [ссылка на чат в котором я выложил ссыки](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97190/opengl---)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @vegorov-у он дал мне ответ.

**Вот заголовочный файл**

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/usr/include/glm  \ # если не заработает попробуй полный путь $$PWD/../../../../../usr/include/glm
```

**вот полный код с выводом :**

```
#define GLM_FORSE_RADIANS   // углы будут задоваться в радианах
#define GLM_SWIZZLE

#include <glm/vec2.hpp>
#include <glm/matrix.hpp>
#include <glm/mat2x2.hpp>
#include <glm/geometric.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    glm::vec2 a(1.0f);       // 1.0f, 1.0f
    cout << "a(x) = " << a.x << " a(y) = " << a.y;
    glm::vec2 b = a +1.0f;   // 2.0f, 2.0f
    cout << "\nb(x) = " << b.x << " b(y) = " << b.y;
    printf("\n----------------");
    // дополнил для себя  чтоб знать скока и чего весит
    float len = glm::length(a);
    cout <<"\nlen = "<< len;
    float len1 = glm::length(b);
    cout <<"\nlen1 = "<< len1;
    float dist = glm::distance(a,b);
    cout <<"\ndist = "<< dist;
    printf("\n----------------");
    glm::vec2 c(2.0f, -1.0f);
    cout << "\nc(x) = " << c.x << " c(y) = " << c.y;
    glm::vec2 d = a+2.0f*c;                     // сложение и умножение на число
    cout << "\nd(x) = " << d.x << " b(y) = " << d.y;
    glm::vec2 e = -d;
    cout << "\ne(x) = " << e.x << " e(y) = " << e.y;
    printf("\n----------------");
    glm::vec2 f = glm::normalize(e);
    cout << "\nf(x) = " << f.x << " f(y) = " << f.y;
    glm::vec2 a2(a.x);
    cout << "\na2(x) = " << a2.x << " b(y) = " << b.y << endl;
    printf("----------------\n");
    /*
     *  ВАЖНО этот код выдаёт ошибку: ‘glm::vec2 {aka struct glm::vec<2, float, (glm::qualifier)0>}’ has no member named ‘xy’ glm::vec2 a2(a.xy);
     */
    //    glm::vec2 a2(a.xy);
    //    glm::vec2 b2(a.xy);
    //    glm::vec2 b2(a.y());

    float dot2 = glm::dot(glm::vec2(1),d); // скаляроное произведение
    cout << "dot2 = " << dot2 << endl;
    float len_new = glm::length(e);         // длинна вектора
    cout << "len_new = " << len_new << endl;
    float dist1 = glm::distance(b, c);
    cout << "dist1 = " << dist1 << endl;   // растояне между векторами
    bool res = glm::all(glm::equal(a, b));
    cout << "res = " << res << endl;
    printf("----------------\n");

    glm::mat2 m(0,1,2,3);
    cout << "m[0] = " << m[0][0] <<" m[1] = " << m[0][1] << " m[2] = " << m[1][0] << " m[3] = " << m[1][1] << endl;
    glm::mat2 n = glm::matrixCompMult(m,m);     // покомпонентоное перемножение
    cout << "n[0] = " << n[0][0] <<" n[1] = " << n[0][1] << " n[2] = " << n[1][0] << " n[3] = " << n[1][1] << endl;
    glm::mat2 t = glm::transpose(m);            // транспонирование
    cout << "t[0] = " << t[0][0] <<" t[1] = " << t[0][1] << " t[2] = " << t[1][0] << " t[3] = " << t[1][1] << endl;
    glm::mat2 mi = glm::inverse(m);             // получаем обратную матрицу
    cout << "mi[0] = " << mi[0][0] <<" mi[1] = " << mi[0][1] << " mi[2] = " << mi[1][0] << " mi[3] = " << mi[1][1] << endl;
    printf("----------------\n");
    glm::vec2 u = mi*c+a;                       // умножение матрицы на вектор
    cout << "u(x) = " << u.x << " u(y) = " << u.y << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

**а вот результат :**
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]